# How to call a function pointer with arguments

Tags: c++, function, pointers

I have created a function pointer

```
void(Status::*StatusFormImageChange)(bool);
```

Now I want to call it with an argument. But when I try to call with

```
StatusFormImageChange(true);
```

I get an error

> The expression doesn't give a function which takes one argument

Comment: Sorry, but that doesn't help me. I think the links says that it should be called with *(StatusFormImageChange)(true); but that doen't worl either.

Comment: The link says you need to call it with an object of the relevant class, like this `(my_status.*StatusFormImageChange)(true)`.

Comment: And why does it work  for pointers which don't get any arguments without any object like StatusFormImageChange; ?

Comment: Do you mean non-member function pointers? That works because they don't require an object to operate on. Think about what it would mean to call a member function without an object; it doesn't make sense.

Comment: Ok. How is a non-member function pointer called with arguments?

Comment: When I see this: http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/function-pointers.html it is straightforward. He is calling it wight foo( 2 ); but I don't understand why that doesn't work with my code.

Comment: @Christoph Because your code is calling a member function. You need to do that with an object, just like when you're calling a member function normally by name.

Comment: So sorry. But I don't get that. Why is there such a difference between NoArgument/Argument calls? For the member function with no passed arguments, I don't need any objects. That makes no sense. When I implement functions that can be called without any object reference, I always can implement functions with arguments too. Or am I wrong?

Comment: @Christoph Calling a member function pointer with no arguments looks like `(obj.*fn)();`. Contrast with simply `fn;` : the latter simply names the member function pointer, but does nothing at all : it's not a function call.